How to keep the cursor in the current position after closing the Find and Replace panel in TeXstudio?
I'm using TeXstudio for LaTeX editing, and I have an issue with the Find and Replace feature. Every time I close the Find and Replace panel after making replacements, the cursor automatically jumps to the last replaced instance. I would like to keep the cursor at its current position (where it was before closing the panel) instead of it moving to the last replacement.
I've checked the settings under Options > Configure TeXstudio, but I couldn't find any specific option to disable this behavior. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Closing the panel with the Esc key instead of clicking the close button.
Exploring the settings under "Search Panel" and "Special options" sections.
Is there any way to prevent the cursor from jumping to the last replaced position when I close the Find and Replace panel in TeXstudio? Or is there a workaround for this?
